# std::cout does not output if called from custom allocator (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to work out how to use custom allocators. I've written a basic allocator that inherits from std::allocator, and am using std::cout to attempt to trace its execution. Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct myIntAllocator : std::allocator<int>
{
    int* allocate(size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
        return new int[size];
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    std::vector<int, myIntAllocator> ints;
    ints.push_back(1);
}
```

Output:

```
foo
```

I'm expecting it to output `bar` as well, but this does not appear.

Am I missing some magic to making `std::cout` work in this way? Or have I misunderstood how to use allocators?

I'm using MSVC v142 in Visual Studio 2019, compiler optimizations off.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Do you have any idea if `std::cout` "ignores" certain things depending on context? I've turned off compiler optimizations with the same result

Comment: Seems to work with `clang`, only `gcc` yields the described behavior.

Comment: could it be that allocate doesn't get called ?

Comment: @darune It's a possibility, but I'm not sure how to debug that. If it indeed is not being called, then why is it working in `clang` according to @lubgr, but not in `gcc` or `MSVC`?

Comment: @vkn that is easy to answer: implementation details

Comment: Also see my answer - I try to explain why you shouldn't inherit `std::allocator`

Comment: As the duplicate explains, you haven't properly implemented `rebind`. Deriving from `std::allocator` hides this bug and that's one of the reasons you shouldn't do it. (Try adding `template <typename U> struct rebind { typedef myIntAllocator other; };` and it will work.)

Comment: @David I see now. I tried diving into `vector`s implementation on my copy and I'll probably be having nightmares for the next week. Standard library is a fickle mistress indeed! Thanks for finding that duplicate, lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Am I missing some magic to making std::cout work in this way? Or have
>   I misunderstood how to use allocators?

In a way, yes - normally you do ***not*** want to inherit and overload an allocator, as that will just makes things more messy and expose you to slicing/up-cast. The other point is that for what we know, vector or allocator could have some implementation details we are not aware of as well. The logical explaination is *still* that your function do not get called.

Comment: It's `std::allocator` that has the implementation details he wasn't aware of.

Comment: "*normally you do wan't to inherit and overload an allocator*" - did you actually mean to say DON'T instead of DO?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, indeed, I fixed that now